# buildout+setuptools and git project fork

Tags: python, django, git, buildout

In project I have used some 3rd party application. Now it looks it's no more supported, so I have created a fork of this application on git for my needs.

How should I configure buildout so I will be able to make some changes in this application and then use it in my project? Formerly this application was in dependencies of setup.py. Right I am not sure how should I organize buildout and setuptools configuration.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you want to continue development on the Git package, I'd use [`mr.developer`](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/mr.developer) to manage the package. `mr.developer` will mark the egg as a developer egg, which means it'll not be pulled from PyPI but used locally.

Moreover, `mr.developer` will manage the working copy for you:

```
[buildout]
extensions = mr.developer
auto-checkout = your.package.name

[sources]
your.package.name = git git@github.com:yourgitname/your.package.name.git
```

Now, when running your buildout, `mr.developer` will automatically check out `your.package.name` from git into the `src/` subdirectory, run it's setup.py to make a development egg, and buildout will use that egg to satisfy dependencies on it.

If you need a different sources directory, use the `sources-dir` option:

```
[buildout]
# ...
sources-dir = ${buildout:directory}/some-other/directory
```

Comment: Can mr.developer put it in other dir rather than in src/. Logically it's still 3rd part library and I don't want it in my src directory.

Comment: @sunprophit: sure it can, use the `sources-dir` option.